# How to change sizeHint after showing widgets in actual?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyside

I made a `widgetAction`.

I set `sizeHint (100, 30)` as a Default setting.

I set the `widgetAction` to the menu of `QPushButton()`

the QPushButton is aligned by `QVBoxLayout()`

So, the size of `QPushButton` is often changed by stretching... resizing... minimized... and so on.

But the labels of widgetAction are not changed.

Is there a way to change the size of `sizeHint()` after showing it?

I want to resize the label of `widgetAction` to the same size of `QPushButton`

[image: the menu of widgetAction is not the same size of the menu button]

```
from PySide import QtGui
from PySide import QtCore
import sys
class Window(QtGui.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(Window, self).__init__(parent)
        self.menubar = QtGui.QMenuBar()
        self.a_menu = QtGui.QMenu("a-menu")  
        self.label_A = UnderlineStyleLabel(self.a_menu,QtGui.QTextCharFormat.WaveUnderline)        
        self.widgetAction = QtGui.QWidgetAction(self.a_menu)
        self.widgetAction.createWidget(self.label_A)
        self.widgetAction.setDefaultWidget(self.label_A)
        self.a_menu.addAction(self.widgetAction)        
        self.menubar.addMenu(self.a_menu)
        self.setMenuBar(self.menubar)
        self.show()   
class UnderlineStyleLabel(QtGui.QWidget):
    def __init__(self,parent=None,underlineStyle=QtGui.QTextCharFormat.NoUnderline):
        super(UnderlineStyleLabel, self).__init__(parent=None)
        self.setParent(parent)
        self.pen_linepath = QtGui.QPainterPath(QtCore.QPointF(0, 0))        
        self.pen_linepath.lineTo(100, 0)
        self.underlineStyle = underlineStyle
        self.initial_size = QtCore.QSize(100, 30)
    def sizeHint(self):
        return self.initial_size
    def mousePressEvent(self, event):
        self.initial_size = QtCore.QSize(200,30)
        print("mousePressEvent pressed! please change the size!")
    def paintEvent(self,event):
        pen = QtGui.QPen()
        if self.underlineStyle == QtGui.QTextCharFormat.WaveUnderline:
            pen = QtGui.QPen()
            pen.setStyle(QtCore.Qt.PenStyle.SolidLine)
            pen.setWidth(10)
            pen.setColor(QtCore.Qt.black)
            painter = QtGui.QPainter()
            if not painter.isActive():
                painter.begin(self)
            painter.setPen(pen)
            painter.setRenderHint(QtGui.QPainter.RenderHint.Antialiasing)
            painter.drawArc(10, 10, 10, 10, 480, 1920)
            painter.drawArc(20, 7, 10, 10, -480, -1920)
            painter.drawArc(30, 10, 10, 10, 480, 1920)
            painter.drawArc(40, 7, 10, 10, -480, -1920)
            painter.drawArc(50, 10, 10, 10, 480, 1920)
            painter.drawArc(60, 7, 10, 10, -480, -1920)
            painter.end()
        return QtGui.QWidget.paintEvent(self,event)
def main():

    try:
        QtGui.QApplication([])
    except Exception as e:
        print(18,e)
    w = Window()
    sys.exit(QtGui.QApplication.exec_())
if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your action is embedded in a `QWidgetAction`. So, you need to resize the parent widget of your `self.label_A`, also.

If you add the line `self.parent().resize(self.initial_size)` at the end of `UnderlineStyleLabel.mousePressEvent`, the label will be well resized.

Comment: I'm sorry for a long time of no reply. I concentrated on my development. I could change my menu size. But I have not understood the mechanism clearly yet.But Your answer helps me. QMenu, if it has no text, whatever I set it into the menubar of MainWindow, it doesn't appear. But if I write a text to it, the text menu appears by the size of texts. So there is a trick to change the QMenu Size. It is very different from other usual widgets.